# cv2 resolution of captured picture

Tags: python, opencv

Hello I have this simple code:

```
from cv2 import *
import time
# initialize the camera


for x in range (10):
    cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
    s,img = cam.read()
    imwrite(str(x) + ".jpg",img) #save image
    time.sleep(3)
    print(x)
    cam.release()
```

I wonder about two things:
- the default resolution of my webcam is higher than resolution that script is saving my picture with? 
- is there any command to check max resolution of webcam (I would like to set this res as default output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is way to check the default resolution of your webcam.

- First initiate the webcam using `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`.
- Then using the `get()` method, enter the following and on printing `w` and `h` you will get the width and height of your webcam:

  ```
  w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
  h = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
  ```

This is in response to your second question. Yes, you can alter the resolution of your webcam by choosing a width and height of your choice using the following `set()` method:

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
```

Even though you change the width and height, the camera driver maintains an aspect ratio. So you may not always get the exact height/width you expect.

Example: when I set the width and height to be 80 each. It did not set it. It rather set width = 320 and height = 180. Also when I set both to 800 it returned width = 848 and height = 480.

The camera driver this maintains an aspect ratio.

Comment: No effect for me - had to use cv2.resize :\